# Fit image or print image

Tags: qgis

I am not able to extend the image to the edges of the paper. How to extend the edges of the image to the edges of the paper?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the scale from the right side menu?

Comment: Yes. My current scale in the image is 1152877778. It is very difficult to manage.

Answer (score 1):

First, go to the layers panel. Right click export, save as. Then in the window 'Save Raster Layer as...' select under extent 'current layer extent.' Read the dimensions.
Go to the composer to make a layout. Fill in the dimensions correctly in under 'item properties, extents'(tip: look a rulers). Now go in 'item properties, position and size.' Change the page size.
Somehow it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change the scale until your data fills the whole map-canvas.

Comment: I cannot do that, because then sides of the map are missing.

Comment: I imported an 5905x5905 pixels png image to work with. Now, I need the same size 5905x5905 pixels png image adjusted version of QGIS. I want to export it, but I do not know how.

Comment: Just convert it to your desired file format (`Raster - conversion - convert`)

Comment: It are two layers with one above the other. Sorry, I did not mention. However, I cannot understand convert as a way of exporting it to a png. Do I miss something? It is outside the composer right?

Comment: I know understand how to export something from the layer panel. However, I cannot export it as like the two layers combined. Do you know a way to merge two layers? Or do you know a better solution?

Comment: How about you provide some additional information in your post, then we'll see, if and how we can help you.